# Replaces vlaues in second column of file based on anoter matching id of anoter file

Tags: awk, sed

I have two files like this, the file2 was separated by tabs：

file1

```
A 
B
E
```

file2

```
ID value
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
E   5
F   6
GA  7
HB  10
I   11
```

I want to replace the value of the second column with 0 if the id is present in file1 like this

```
ID  value
A   0
B   0
C   3
D   4
E   0
F   6
GA  7
HB  10
I   11
```

I wrote a very stupid code

```
for i in `cat file1`;do sed -i 's/\<'"$i"'\>/'"$i"'\t0/g' file2;done

less -S file2 | awk '{print $1,"\t",$2}' | sed 's/ //g' > finalfile
```

Any fluent code can be replaced like awk way?appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing all the work with `awk`.

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
  NR==FNR{ Ids[$1]; next }
         { print $1, ($1 in Ids?0:$2) }
' file1 file2
```